# iOS Upgrading Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to migrate my data to the new version of Firebase and I am having some trouble with creating a user and logging them in (Email and Password).

Here is my part of old data. After creating a user, I log them in and capture the password as authData.provider!. This would store the password as just "Password" in my data structure. I am struggling with finding the new "authData.provider! in the the Firebase SDK.

```
ref.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { err, authData in

     let user = ["provider": authData.provider!, "email": email!, "username": username!]
```

Here is the new code I am replacing the above code with.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in

     let userLocal = ["provider": user!.providerData.description, "email": email!, "username": username!]
```

I found that authData.provider! != user!.providerData.description, and I can't find what authData.provider! is in the new SDK.
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. used user!.providerID

```
let userLocal = ["provider": user!.providerID, "email": email!, "username": username!]
```